# How to build dynamic query on Elasticsearch, which will execute on Node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

When I tried to create query like

```
var my_query = new Object("[{ \"match\": { \"techskills.programming\":"+ programming+" } }]");

var deferred = Q.defer();
client.search({
    "index": _index,
    "type": _type,
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": my_query
            }
        }
    }
},function (error,resp) {
    console.log("Found error is ::::: "+error + " resp::: "+JSON.stringify(resp));
    if(error) deferred.reject(error);
    deferred.resolve(resp);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

I am getting the following error:

> [query_parsing_exception] [bool] query does not support [must]

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this by creating complete body tag as dynamic query string and passed this variable to the elasticsearch query.
ex: 
 var my_query = "{\"query\": {\"bool\":{\"must\": [{ \"match\": { \"techskills.programming\":\"" + programming + "\"} }]}}}"

client.search({
        "index": _index,
        "type": _type,
        **body:my_query**
    },function (error,resp) {
        console.log("Found error is ::::: "+error + " resp::: "+JSON.stringify(resp));
        if(error) deferred.reject(error);
        deferred.resolve(resp);
    });

Comment: Thank you so much, i spend one whole afternoon trying to achieve that lol